# how to prove that a matrix is definitely invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

T $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

prove that any given matrix on image of T excluding the zero matrix is definitely an invertible matrix.

oh and a,b,c,d $\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3):

The determinant is $a^2 + b^2$, which is non-zero for all $(a,b) \ne (0,0)$.

Comment: No, for $a=i$ and $b=1$ it is zero, since $i^2+1=0$.

Comment: sorry i updated my question now...

Comment: and he was right. how didnt i look at the determinant...